# Is the ratio of two distinct zeros of a Bessel function of the first kind an irrational number?

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions, bessel-functions

Let $J_1$ be the Bessel function of the first kind with parameter $\alpha=1$. Namely, $J_1$ satisfies the differential equation for $y$ given by $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-1)y=0$ and $J_1(0)=0$.

Is it true that if $x_1>0$ and $x_2>0$ are two distinct zeros of $J_1$, then $x_1/x_2$ is an irrational number? An affirmative answer is equivalent to saying that for every $a>0$ the arithmetic progression $\{na\ |\ n\in\mathbb N \}$ contains at most one zero of $J_1$.